# I can pass a cookie in my http post with clj-http

Tags: clojure

when I use postman my handler can get the cookie without problem, I just add it to my header, now I'm writing my test and using clj-http for send the request to my rest server, first I try do it by hand and add my cookie in the header

```
(:status (http/post "http://localhost:8080/create/article"
                    {:throw-exceptions false}
                    {:body         "...."
                     :headers      {"Cookie" "uid-session=12"}
                     :content-type "application/json"}))
```

and also I try using the cookie property

```
(is (= 200 (:status (http/post "http://localhost:8080/create/article"
                               {:throw-exceptions false}
                               {:cookies      {"uid-session" {:value "12"}}
                                :body         " ... "
                                :content-type "application/json"}))))
```

debugging my app my handler doesn't receive any cookie, what could be the reason?...thanks

Comment: You should be more careful when formatting your code to make it easier to read. You have blank lines for no reason and a bare `}))))`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're calling `http/post` incorrectly: You're passing two different sets of request options, but it ignores all but the first one, which is `{:throw-exceptions false}`.

(I consider it a bug in clj-http that it behaves so unhelpfully in this case, by not signalling an error. Maybe someone should [open an issue](https://github.com/dakrone/clj-http/issues)...)

If you do this it will work (at least it did for me):

```
(http/post
  "http://localhost:8080/create/article"
  {:throw-exceptions false
   :body "...."
   :headers {"Cookie" "uid-session=12"}
   :content-type "application/json"})
```